# How to fire a click? after a change event on a select in agularjs on safari

Tags: angularjs, trigger, safari

i have a big problem in safari when i try to fire click event on an input file, after and inside a change event (onchange, ng-change, $scope.watch... etc, i tried all). this works fine in chrome, explorer, but not in SAFARI.  Here is an example of my code, with two forms to fire click:

```
$scope.mialerta = function(event) {
      $timeout(function() {
        alert("alerta");
//solution one
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent("click", true, true); 
        document.getElementById('file_documents_first').dispatchEvent(evt);

//solution two        angular.element(document.querySelector('#file_documents_first')).trigger('click');


      });
    };

<select name="cedula" id="cedula" class="form-control col-md-8"
                        ng-model="cedula" 
                        ng-change="mialerta()"
                        ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in options" ></select>

<input type="file" id="file_documents_first" name="file_documents_first" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.pdf" ng-model="file_documents_first" >
```

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está en inglés y debería ser traducida antes de poder ser aceptada en [es.so].

Comment: Hola Devojoker y bienvenido a SO en español.  Sería necesario que traduzcas tu pregunta y podrá ser reabierta.